# How to transform a non-homogeneous Neumann boundary condition into a homogeneous for the wave equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have a initial/ boundary value problem for standard wave equation
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=c\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2},
$$
where one of the boundary conditions is non-homogeneous: precisely $$
\frac{\partial u(0,t)}{\partial x}=e^t.
$$
**Question**: is it possible to transform the above problem into a one with homogeneous boundary conditions?

In the Q&A "[*Solve wave equation and inhomogeneous Neumann Condition with eigenfunction expansion (Fourier Series Solution)*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3267024/solve-wave-equation-and-inhomogeneous-neumann-condition-with-eigenfunction-expan)" I saw a similar reduction, but I am unable to apply the method proposed there to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should find a function $v(x, t) = A(t) x^2 + B(t) x + C(t)$ that satisfies boundary conditions (in your case $\partial_x v (0,t) = e^t$). And you can find solution of your problem as $u = v + w$. For function $w$ you get a problem for wave equation with homogenous boundary conditions.

Comment: THX, but I only have two BCs for $v(x,t)$, how about the third unknown in $v(x,t)$?

Comment: @majordoctor you can select any function $v$, which satisfies boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the most general form of the solution of the 1D wave equation is
$$u(x,t)=f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)$$
So,
$$\partial_x u(x,t)=f'(x-ct)+g'(x+ct)$$
$$\partial_x u(0,t)=f'(-ct)+g'(ct)=e^t$$
Since we still have two unknown functions $f,g$ your condition is not yet enough to determine a unique solution.